# How do I remove someone from a Google Group without them being notified?

Tags: google-groups

I am the admin for a Google Groups email list via groups.google.com (i.e., not a private Apps domain). I want to remove someone from the email list *without* them being notified. Is this possible? If so how? (Perhaps no notification is ever issued -- the [docs](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2647680) are not clear.)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, removing someone from a Google Group doesn't alert them with an email.

I just tried it on a regular Google Group (not associated with an Apps for Work account). Adding someone to a Google Group sends an email, although removing someone does not.